# Apache does not interpret php code

Tags: apache2, php

I have recently had to uninstall and reinstall a LAMP stack on Ubuntu 20.10. Everything appears to go well, except that PHP code is not interpreted. It appears that the PHP module is not loaded.

The restart at the end of the sequence below made no difference.

So it looks as though I need to add something to an apache config file, but I don't really understand the way the config files work on Ubuntu.

Can anyone help?

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  libapache2-mod-php php
0 actualizados, 2 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 5,676 B de archivos.
Se utilizarán 30.7 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
Des:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php all 2:7.4+76 [2,904 B]
Des:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 php all 2:7.4+76 [2,772 B]
Descargados 5,676 B en 2s (2,728 B/s)
Seleccionando el paquete libapache2-mod-php previamente no seleccionado.
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 530220 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmen
te.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../libapache2-mod-php_2%3a7.4+76_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libapache2-mod-php (2:7.4+76) ...
Seleccionando el paquete php previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../php_2%3a7.4+76_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando php (2:7.4+76) ...
Configurando php (2:7.4+76) ...
Configurando libapache2-mod-php (2:7.4+76) ...
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$ a2query -m php
No module matches php
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$ a2query -m php7
No module matches php7
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$ php -v
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2020 15:17:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$ a2query -m php7.4
No module matches php7.4
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$ apachectl configtest
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install PHP first via `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-phpX.Y` (in case it's missing) and then enable it with `sudo a2enmod phpX.Y`. Restart `apache2` and PHP should work fine.

In case you want to enable HTTP2 support: `sudo apt install phpX.Y-fpm` and `sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi`

Comment: I get an error about conflicts: peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/websites/test$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.4:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Module mpm_event is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php7.4, aborting

Comment: You did not specify this. Please try `sudo apt install phpX.Y-fpm` and `sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi`.

Comment: Sorry. Not sure why I didn't specify the error before. Anyway, I tried your suggestion, but still have the same problem, even after a reboot.

Comment: Please post a list of enabled apache modules.

Comment: mpm_event
negotiation
env
authz_user
alias
dir
authn_file
setenvif
status
auth_basic
proxy
authn_core
mime
authz_core
autoindex
authz_host
deflate
reqtimeout
proxy_fcgi
access_compat
filter

Comment: `sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi`, like BulletBob described, did the trick for me. On Ubuntu 20.04, Apache used to work fine, but after upgrading to 20.10, it refused to start. I thought my experience might be useful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it fixed. The answer was to disable mpm_event. The PHP module could then be loaded.

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
systemctl restart apache2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

Unfortunately mpm_event could not be reloaded. Attempting to do so returned another error saying there was a conflict with mpm_prefork.

Despite this, apache2 restarted just fine and is working with the very basic PHP pages I have used as tests. Whether or not I'll encounter problems in the future due to mpm_event not being loaded remains to be seen.